# Epimorphisms preserved by pullback functor with right adjoint

Tags: category-theory, adjoint-functors, pullback

I am working through some notes, and am on a section about locally cartesian closed categories. One of the results is if $\mathcal{C}$ is local cartesian closed and has coequalisers of reflexive pairs, then all morphisms have a factorisation into a regular epic followed by a monic.

The proof seems to rely on the following:

**Claim:** Let the pullback functor $f^*:\mathcal{C}/B\to \mathcal{C}/A$ (induced by $f:A\to B$ in $\mathcal{C}$) have a right adjoint. Then pulling back an epic along $f$ preserves epicness.

I can't understand why this is true since an epic in $\mathcal{C}$ is just an object of $\mathcal{C}/B$, not an arrow. So even if $f^*$ preserves colimits (hence epics), it is preserving epics in $\mathcal{C}/B$, not $\mathcal{C}$. If someone could explain to me how this works that would be very helpful.

Comment: No the point is to say that if $ g \in C/B $ is an object that is epic as an arrow in $ C $, then the object $ f^*g \in C/A $ is epic as an arrow in $ C $

Comment: Sorry, I maybe did not word my question well, but your statement is precisely what I cannot prove. Since $f^*g$ is just an object in $C/A$, i do not understand how you can say that "$f^*$ has preserved the epicness of $g$" (since they are just objects from the point of view of $f^*$).

Comment: Oh right I thought you didn't understand the statement and wanted to know what it meant

Comment: Ah sorry, yes I do understand what the claim is asking, just have no idea how to prove it! Do you happen to know a proof/reference for this result? The few places I've seen mention the result explicitly don't seem to provide much justification past the fact that left adjoints preserve colimits (hence epics) but how that immediately gives this result I'm not sure (since we're not even applying $f^*$ to a morphism).

Comment: I don't know a reference and I don't know a proof but here's an idea : if $ g : D \to B $ is epi, then it is also epi if you see it as a morphism from $ g $ to $ id : B \to B $. Therefore, the *morphism* $ f^*g $  is epi too (in $ C/A $ ). Perhaps with some work one can relate that to its epicness in $ C $ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments to Mark's answer, this is a proof of the claim in the question with the assumption that $C$ has products and pullbacks (and no assumptions of (local) cartesian closedness). I don't know if that helps, because as they stand the hypotheses of the question do not (seem to - at least to me - EDIT : apparently Balaji Krishna assumes products in their definition of local cartesian closedness, so in this case it is sufficient) imply the existence of products.

So let $f:A\to B$ be such that $f^* : C/B\to C/A$ has a right adjoint, in particular it preserves pushouts and thus epis (epis in $C/B$, of course)

Now let $g:D\to B$ be an epi, we wish to show that $f^*g : D\to A$ is epi *in $C$*. 
To avoid confusion, I will write objects of the comma categories as couples.

Note that $g$ can also be seen as a morphism $(D,g)\to (B,id_B)$, and obviously this morphism is epi in $C/B$. Therefore, applying $f^*$ to it is still epi. Now you can check that $f^*$ of the morphism $g$ is actually still $f^*g$ (for the simple reason that $f^*(B,id_B) = (A,id_A)$ and that $f^*$(morphism $g$) is a morphism from $f^*(D,g)$ to $f^*(B,id_B)=(A,id_A)$.

Therefore $f^*g$ is epi in $C/A$, when it's seen as a morphism to $(A,id_A)$. Now we are reduced to the following claim :

> Let $C$ be a category with products, and assume $k : (D,g) \to (E,h)$ is epi in $C/A$. Then $k:D\to E$ is epi.

(I am too lazy to draw the diagrams on here, but it's much better if you do that)

Proof : Let $l_1,l_2 : E\to T$ be arrows in $C$ such that $l_1\circ k = l_2\circ k$; and consider the object $(T\times E, h\circ \pi_E)$ of $C/A$. Then we have, for $i\in\{1,2\}$, a map $\tilde{l_i} : (E,h)\to (T\times E, h\circ \pi_E)$ : on $T$ it's $l_i$ and on $E$ it's $id_E$. It is very easy to see that it's a map of $C/A$, moreover one easily checks that $\tilde{l_1}\circ k = \tilde{l_2}\circ k$, so that by epi-ness of $k$ in $C/A$, $\tilde{l_1}=\tilde{l_2}$.

Now look at the $T$ coordinate, you get $l_1=l_2$, so $k$ is epi in $C$.

It follows that $f^*g$ is epi in $C$ and we are done.

Answer (score 3):

The important thing to note here is that an arrow $g: X \to B$ is an epimorphism if and only if the square
$\require{AMScd}$
$$
\begin{CD}
X @>g>> B\\
@VgVV @VV Id_B V\\
B @>>Id_B> B
\end{CD}
$$
is a pushout. In a slice category, colimits are computed just as in the underlying category (see e.g. [proposition 3.4 on this nLab page](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/over+category#LimitsAndColimits) for the dual statement). That means that if $g$ is an epi in $\mathcal C$, then the above pushout will also be a pushout in $\mathcal C / B$. Then since the pullback functor $f^*: \mathcal C / B \to \mathcal C / A$ has a right adjoint, it preserves colimits and thus in particular it preserves pushouts. Therefore, we have a pushout
$$
\begin{CD}
f^*(X) @>f^*(g)>> A\\
@V f^*(g) VV @VV Id_A V\\
A @>>Id_A> A
\end{CD}
$$
in $\mathcal{C} / A$, which by the same result as before means that this is a pushout in $\mathcal C$. Then we can conclude that $f^*(g)$ is indeed an epimorphism in $\mathcal C$.

**Edit:** as was pointed out in the comments below, the last step is not as trivial as I first thought. The problem is that the second square may not be a pushout in $\mathcal C$. So far we have only shown that it is a pushout in $\mathcal{C}/A$. From that we can conclude that $f^*(g)$ is an epimorphism in $\mathcal{C}/A$.

An [answer by Max](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3196130/661457) to this question shows that when $\mathcal{C}$ has products, then an epimorphism in $\mathcal{C}/A$ is also an epimorphism in $\mathcal{C}$. See the little 'proposition' (yellow block) towards the end of his answer. Whether or not $\mathcal{C}$ is supposed to have products seems to be more of an issue with what exact definition is used, as is apparent from the comments on this answer.

Another way is to note that the forgetful functor $\mathcal{C} / A \to \mathcal{C}$ has $(-) \times A: \mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{C} / A$ as right adjoint. So in particular, the forgetful functor will preserve epimorphisms.

Comment: To make it absolutely clear, when you say "the above pushout will also be a pushout in $C/B$", you mean if we add $B$'s everywhere, right ?That is, the objects of the pushout are $X\to B$ and $B\to B$ three times ? Same for $C/A$

Comment: Hi Mark, thanks for your reference to that nLab result. I am just having one issue applying it here. The (dual of) that referenced result requires the colimit to already exist in $C$, at which point we say colimits in $C/A$ are just built in $C$ in the obvious way. However we are not assuming that $C$ even has pushouts. Therefore is it not possible that $C/A$ may have a colimit which didn't come from $C$? Namely I do not understand why the pushout square witnessing that $f^*g$ is epic in $C/A$ gives a pushout square in $C$, when we haven't assumed one even exists.

Comment: @BalajiKrishna - $C$ doesn't need to have all pushouts in order for *some* pushouts to exist. In particular, if it has an epimorphism, *it has a pushout of the kind in the first diagram above*.

Comment: @Max Yes, that is right.

Comment: @MaliceVidrine I know that requiring all pushouts is much stronger than necessary, but to apply the nLab result, would we not need to assume at minimum that the diagram with the two legs being morphisms $f^*g:f^*X\to A$ has pushout in $C$? I know this specific pushout _could_ exist even if $C$ doesn't have all pushouts, but we haven't assumed it.

Comment: @BalajiKrishna - Though the nLab link is linked to before Mark mentions the colimit preserving property of left adjoint functors, that left adjoint functors preserve colimits tells you immediately that the diagram is a pushout.

Comment: @MaliceVidrine : but a pushout in $ C/A $, why is it a pushout in $ C $ ?

Comment: @Max We are in a Cartesian category, so the forgetful functor out of $C/A$ has multiplication with $A$ as a right adjoint.

Comment: @KevinCarlson indeed, thank you !

Comment: @KevinCarlson sorry to bother you with this, but actually I don't think "cartesian" is in the hypotheses here (or am I missing something, like it would follow from the condition on coequalizers - which would seem odd, but you never know ?)

Comment: And if we do have products, then the proof I suggested in the comments under the question can be completed and is probably simpler

Comment: @Max for the main result this claim is used for, we do assume $C$ is locally cartesian closed, so it is ok. I am curious though how would the proof work with just existence of products in $C$?

Comment: @BalajiKrishna locally cartesian closed doesn't imply you have products though, you need something like a terminal object to get there. I will write an answer with no hypothesis on $C$ except for the existence of products.

Comment: @Max Hmm both my lecture notes and nLab seem to assume that (locally) cartesian closed categories do have finite products (since for an object to be exponentiable you need to be able to times by it), but in any case am interested in a proof with fewer hypotheses required.

Comment: Well of course if "locally" is in parentheses you have products, but https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/locally+cartesian+closed+category doesn't seem to mention products in $C$ (the comma categories have products, because *they* are cartesian closed). Though the nLab states that it's sometimes included in the definition, so I won't argue for too long about it ;)

Comment: @Max Good point. For me locally cartesian closed categories are cartesian closed. It seems weird to assume something as strong as relative exponentials but refuse a terminal object, though I can understand someone might want to do it. If so perhaps there's a counterexample, I don't know!

Comment: It seems that my answer was indeed a bit short in the last step. I will refer to your answer, @Max, because your little 'proposition' precisely solves that problem (modulo this entire discussion about $\mathcal C$ being cartesian closed or not).